# How to use importxml in google sheets to import item hidden by scroll into view

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I need to import the shipping costs hidden by this "Scroll into view" via IMPORTXML into Google Sheets.

[image: Photo one]

I can find the Xpath in the HTML for the =IMPORTXML into Sheets but it comes up empty.

[image: Photo two]

Apparently Sheets can't import items that aren't in view so I need a method of clicking the window open so IMPORTXML will work. Some type of script possibly?

I attempted a thorough search of past questions and tried to include more photos but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

So One way to get the data on the shipping item is by taking elements from the item url so you can retrieve the shipping items data:

Lets say you have the following URL in `A1`: http://www.gearbest.com/multi-rotor-parts/pp_197627.html?wid=2

The shipping URL looks very similar with a couple differences:  http://www.gearbest.com/shipping/pp_197627.html?act=get_shipping_info&id=197627&num=1&country=41&wid=2

using regexreplace to use the item ID from the original URL, and swap out the webpage parameters to show shipping look like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"?","&"),"(http://www.gearbest.com/)(.*)(/.*.html)","$1shipping$3?act=get_shipping_info&id="&REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d+")&"&num=1&country=41")
```

Before the full regexreplace, I substitute any question marks in the original url to `&`, just in case so that it properly loads the data that you want. Then surrounding that I am basically swapping the `multi-rotor-parts` to `shipping` then appending on `act=get_shipping_info&id=` with another regex that grabs the id # from the originial url in this case it is `197627` and then appending on the end the `&num=1&country=41`  - note that you can also change the `num` parameter to represent the number of items you want the final price for.

If you were to load this url you will see the raw json data that includes all the shipping variations

From there you can use importdata to pull it in, if you want the fields separated you can use importdata by itself:

```
=IMPORTDATA(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"?","&"),"(http://www.gearbest.com/)(.*)(/.*.html)","$1shipping$3?act=get_shipping_info&id="&REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d+")&"&num=1&country=41"))
```

if you want all the text to be loaded in one cell you can wrap it in concatenate like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(IMPORTDATA(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"?","&"),"(http://www.gearbest.com/)(.*)(/.*.html)","$1shipping$3?act=get_shipping_info&id="&REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d+")&"&num=1&country=41")))
```

finally: if you want ultimately only the price and not any other data wrap it all in a regexextract function:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(CONCATENATE(IMPORTDATA(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"?","&"),"(http://www.gearbest.com/)(.*)(/.*.html)","$1shipping$3?act=get_shipping_info&id="&REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d+")&"&num=1&country=41"))),"ship_price:""(.*)""ship.*")
```

[image]